# Making nested dictionary output less convoluted

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, output

Having a challenge trying to get my dictionary's results print out correctly, and without all the convoluted 'for' loops.

```
my_dict = [
            {0:
                  {"Artist": "Pat Metheny",
                        "Albums": {"Bright Size Life": {"Year": "1977"},
                                   "Watercolours": {"Year": "1979"}}
                   }},

              {1:
                  {"Artist": "John Coltrane",
                    "Albums": {"Giant Steps": {"Year": "1964"}}
                   }},

              ]

for x in my_dict:
    y = x.values()
    #print("y is ", y)
    for Artist in y:
        for Artist_name in Artist:
            z = (Artist.items())

        for the_name, artist in z:
            print("Artist: ", artist)

        for album_name in artist:
            print("album :" ,album_name)
            a = artist.items()
        #print("a is ",a)
        for the_year, year_name in a:
                print("Year: ", year_name)
```

the output is which is also printing too much information, and the year incorrectly, is:

```
Artist:  Pat Metheny
Artist:  {'Bright Size Life': {'Year': '1977'}, 'Watercolours': {'Year': '1979'}}
album : Bright Size Life
album : Watercolours
Year:  {'Year': '1977'}
Year:  {'Year': '1979'}
Artist:  John Coltrane
Artist:  {'Giant Steps': {'Year': '1964'}}
album : Giant Steps
Year:  {'Year': '1964'}
```

Comment: What's up with the `0:` and `1:`?

Comment: And also, you call it `my_dict`, but it's actually a list of single-item dictionaries. Did you mean to make a big dictionary out of it instead with `0:` and `1:` as keys?

Comment: To make it less convoluted try recursion instead. And why are `0` and `1` omitted?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, the numbers are just an index of artists, but perhaps they're not really necessary? As Raymond put it in his solution, the artists have metadata, which can be much larger. At this stage, I'm just trying to figure out how to write more complex dictionaries and be able to access and manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
for d in my_dict:
    for entry in d.values():
        print('Artist:', entry['Artist'])
        for album, metadata in entry['Albums'].items():
            year = metadata['Year']
            print(f'{album} ({year})')
        print()
```

This outputs:

```
Artist: Pat Metheny
Bright Size Life (1977)
Watercolours (1979)

Artist: John Coltrane
Giant Steps (1964)
```